# Como selecionar uma opção no <select> através de um texto usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um `<select>` criado desta forma:

```
<select id="animal">
    <option value="0">Novilha</option>
    <option value="1">Bezerro</option>
    <option value="2">Boi</option>
</select>
```

Para mudar a caixa de seleção programaticamente usando jQuery eu uso o seguinte comando:

```
$("#animal").val("1"); /* faz com que  o Bezerro fique selecionado */
```

Porém gostaria de saber como seria passar como parâmetro ao invés do `val("1")` passar o texto. Por exemplo:

```
$("#animal").val("Bezerro");
```

Neste caso ficando selecionado o *option* "Bezerro". Como selecionar uma opção no `<select>` através de um texto usando jQuery ?

Comment: @LucasCosta é só exemplo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seletor [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) e então pegar o valor dele.

```js
$("#animal").val( $('option:contains("Bezerro")').val() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animal">
    <option value="0">Novilha</option>
    <option value="1">Bezerro</option>
    <option value="2">Boi</option>
</select>
```

Dessa forma irá obter o valor do `option` que possuir `Bezerro` e então aplicar o valor do `select`. Ele diferencia letras maiúsculas de minusculas portanto tenha atenção. Apesar do nome (`:contains`) ele não precisa apenas conter a palavra buscada, pelo contrário o termo deve ser idêntico.

*Se houverem dois `option` de "Oi" e outro de "Oi, Tudo Bem?", utilizando o `:contains("Oi")` apenas o primeiro será selecionado.*

---

> Exemplo:

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){nome=$('input').val();$("#animal").val($('option:contains("'+nome+'")').val())})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>Digite uma das opções do Select: <br><input placeholder="pesquisar"><button>Atualizar</button><br><br><select id="animal"> <option value="0">Novilha</option> <option value="1">Bezero</option> <option value="2">Boi</option> <option value="3">Bezero Clone</option></select>
```

Comment: Isso funciona pra mim. =D

Answer (score 6):

## [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

> Selecione todos os elementos que contenham o texto especificado.

```js
$("#animal option:contains(Boi)").attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animal">
    <option value="0">Novilha</option>
    <option value="1">Bezero</option>
    <option value="2">Boi</option>
</select>
```

## [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduza o conjunto de elementos correspondentes para aqueles que
>   combinam com o seletor ou passam o teste da função.

```js
$("#animal option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() =='Bezero';
}).prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animal">
        <option value="0">Novilha</option>
        <option value="1">Bezero</option>
        <option value="2">Boi</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Isso funcionou também! =D

Answer (score 4):

Um jeito diferente:

```js
function selectByText(select, text) {
  $(select).find('option:contains("' + text + '")').prop('selected', true);
}

selectByText('#animal', 'Bezero');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animal">
    <option value="0">Novilha</option>
    <option value="1">Bezero</option>
    <option value="2">Boi</option>
</select>
```

Assim como o amigo @LucasCosta explicou, dessa forma é criada uma função que recebe como parâmetro o seletor do `select` e o texto a ser selecionado, então dentro desse `select` eu procuro a `option` que possui o texto indicado e seleciono ela usando o [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Parece ser bem parecida com a primeira resposta usando option:contains, porém numa função. Pode explicar a diferença?

Comment: Posso sim, vou editar

Comment: Legal dessa forma tb. Aqui ao invés de mudar o `value` diretamente do elemento `animal`, é somente marcado como selecionado o `option` com texto Bezerro @AckLay, como se o usuário tivesse selecionado no drop-down, por isso `prop('selected', true);`.