# Resetar option select

Tags: javascript, html

**JS:**

```
function alterarStatusFunction(val){
    if(val =="aprovado"){
        if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para APROVADO?')) {
            document.formtransacoes.submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select style="width:200px" onchange="alterarStatusFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title);" name="alteraStatus">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">- Opções -</option>
    <option title="aprovado" value="aprovado">Marcar como APROVADO</option>
</select>
```

Como posso fazer para que a opção seja redefinida para o primeiro *option* quando a pessoa clica em cancelar no *alert* que é emitido pelo JS?

Comment: `$("option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() =='- Opções -';
}).prop("selected", true);`, tentou assim?

Comment: Veja: [Como selecionar uma opção no <select> através de um texto usando jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180116/como-selecionar-uma-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-select-atrav%C3%A9s-de-um-texto-usando-jquery/180120#180120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso como tens a opção `disabled` podes usar o `.selectedIndex = 0` assim:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.value = 'aprovado';

setTimeout(() => select.selectedIndex = 0, 2000);
```

```html
<select style="width:200px" onchange="alterarStatusFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title);" name="alteraStatus">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">- Opções -</option>
    <option title="aprovado" value="aprovado">Marcar como APROVADO</option>
</select>

<p>Daqui a 2 segundos será selecionado de novo a opção "disabled".</p>
```

Usando o teu código seria assim:

```js
function alterarStatusFunction(select) {
  var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].title;
  if (val == "aprovado") {
    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para APROVADO?')) {
      document.formtransacoes.submit();
    } else {
      return select.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select style="width:200px" onchange="alterarStatusFunction(this);" name="alteraStatus">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">- Opções -</option>
    <option title="aprovado" value="aprovado">Marcar como APROVADO</option>
    <option title="desaprovado" value="desaprovado">Marcar como DESAPROVADO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso que ele altere assim que clicar em cancelar no alert de confirmação. Quando ele exibe a mensagem "Tem certeza que deseja..." o usuário pode clicar em ok e em cancelar. Se apertar OK ele vai acionar um form, se cancelar não faz nada e fecha a mensagem. Ai que eu preciso que ele resete a opção.

Comment: @CEW juntei um exemplo com o teu código, passando o `this` à função.

Comment: Funcionou, mas ele sempre fica na primeira opção, não aparece qual foi seleciona. No caso ele deve retornar a primeira opção somente quando clicar em cancelar.

Comment: @CEW no teu código há um submit, se abrires a consola vais ver que o browser chama o submit. Não sei o que fazes depois com o submit pois não fazia parte da pergunta/descrição do problema

Comment: Não há relação com o form que é acionado, ele não vem ao caso. O form vai ser acionado somente se apertar ok no diálogo de confirmação. O que preciso é que ao apertar CANCELAR em vez do OK no diálogo ele muda para a primeira opção do select. Ele deve fazer isso somente quando clicar no botão.

Comment: @CEW é isso que o meu código faz, dá uma olhada no segundo exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Basta referenciar o select na função, e usar `selectedIndex` para restaurar.

```js
function alterarStatusFunction(val){
op = val.options[val.selectedIndex].title;
if(op == "aprovado"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para APROVADO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
val.selectedIndex = 0; 
return false;
}
}
}
```

```html
<select style="width:200px" onchange="alterarStatusFunction(this);" name="alteraStatus">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">- Opções -</option>
       <option title="aprovado" value="aprovado">Marcar como APROVADO</option>
      
    </select>
```