# Como pegar o texto da opção selecionada dentro de um select?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<option value="1">item 1</option>
<option value="2">item 1</option>
<option value="3">item 1</option>
```

quero pegar o texto dentro do `<option>` que estiver selecionada. Por exemplo:

texto1 = item 1

Comment: Como sabes qual é a option que queres? é a que está selecionada?

Comment: Sim Sergio é a que está selecionada que eu quero

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como selecionar uma opção no <select> através de um texto usando jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180116/como-selecionar-uma-op%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-select-atrav%c3%a9s-de-um-texto-usando-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes usar usar `select.children[select.selectedIndex]` e depois `textContent`:

Exemplo:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var option = select.children[select.selectedIndex];
var texto = option.textContent;

console.log(texto); // item 2
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>item 2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
```

Essa é a maneira mais antiga/compatível, mas também podes usar `.selectedOptions[0]` que retorna as options selecionadas. Neste caso como é um select não múltiplo ficaria assim:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var option = this.selectedOptions[0];
  var texto = option.textContent;

  console.log(texto);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>item 2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

A [resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/253129/66203) já contempla o que foi pedido, entretanto gostaria de deixar uma alternativa utilizando jQuery:

```js
$('#selectOption').change(function() {
var option = $('#selectOption').find(":selected").text();
console.log(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOption">
    <option value="1">Op1</option>
    <option value="2">Op2</option>
    <option value="3">Op3</option>
    <option value="4">Op4</option>
    <option value="5">Op5</option>
</select>
```

Utilizo o [`.change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) para que quando ocorrer uma mudança no elemento com id igual a *selectOption*, seja encontrada, com o [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) a opção que está selecionada, usando o seletor [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/). E então para fins de resposta devolvo a resposta no console, através de [`console.log()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057/66203).

Pode também fazer dessa outra maneira, um pouco mais simplificada, a qual também é utilizado o [`.change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) para que quando ocorrer uma mudança no elemento com id igual a *selectOption*, seja encontrada a opção do  com o seletor [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), e devolvido no console usando [`console.log()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057/66203), para fins de resposta:

```js
$('#selectOption').change(function() {
var option = $( "#selectOption option:selected" ).text();
console.log(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOption">
    <option value="1">Op1</option>
    <option value="2">Op2</option>
    <option value="3">Op3</option>
    <option value="4">Op4</option>
    <option value="5">Op5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}

var text = getSelectedText('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

Muito obrigado esse post me ajudou muito, parabéns para quem compartilhou e ajudou obrigado mesmo.

Meu código corrigido:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
                                
    //var textAdd = $('#inpudAdd').val();
    var textAdd = $('#inpudAdd').find(":selected").val();
    var textAdd2 = $('#inpudAdd').find(":selected").text();
    
    $('#inpudAdd').val('').focus();
    $('.boxLista').append('<b id="item"><input type="checkbox" name="app[]" id="item" checked="checked" value="' + textAdd + '" > ' + textAdd2 + '</br></b>  ');    

    });
    $(document).on('click', '#item', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $('#button2').click(function(){
        
    //var textAdd = $('#inpudAdd2').val();
    var textAdd = $( "#inpudAdd2 option:selected" ).val();;
    //var textAdd2 = $('#inpudAdd2').find(":selected").text();
    
    $('#inpudAdd2').val('').focus();
    $('.boxLista').append('<b id="item2"><input type="checkbox" name="app[]" id="item2" checked="checked" value="' + textAdd + '" > ' + textAdd + '</br></b>  ');   
        console.log(option);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#item2', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```