# Como faço para mostrar o nome de uma pessoa e não a sua chave em script que usa onclick()?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tendo uma dúvida com o código de exclusão de clientes, ao invés de digitar a chave do cliente para ser excluída eu crei um  que retorna todos os nomes de clientes armazenadas onde escolho um e clico em deletar e pronto.

**Só que ao invés de mostrar `Leandro foi excluído(a) com sucesso` mostra `6 foi excluído(a) com sucesso`, ou seja está mostrando a chave do cliente ao invés do nome** (preciso deixar isso o mais acessível possível por causa que uma pessoa com deficiência visual irá testar então estou deixando mais acessível para ele quando usar o Narrador do Windows).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### O código é esse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title> Remover cliente </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB/css/css.css">
    <script>
        function exibirNome() {
            var nome = document.querySelector("#cdcliente").value;
            if (nome) {
                alert(nome + " foi excluído(a) com sucesso");
            }
        }
    </script>  
</head>
<body> 
    <?php
        require_once '../conexao/conexao.php';  
        if(isset($_POST['Deletar'])){
            $cd_cliente = $_POST['cd_cliente'];
            try {
                $remove = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE cd_cliente = :cd_cliente";
                $remocao = $conexao->prepare($remove);
                $remocao->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente); 
                $remocao->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $falha_remocao) {
                echo "A remoção não foi feita".$falha_remocao->getMessage();
            }
            $seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_cliente, nome FROM cliente");
            $resultado_selecao = $seleciona_nomes->fetchAll();
        }   
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <p> ID cliente:
        <select name="cd_cliente" required="" id="cdcliente" title="Campo para digitar o código do cliente a ser excluído">
            <option value="" title="Escolha abaixo o cliente a ser excluído"> </option>
            <?php
                foreach ($resultado_selecao as $valor) {
                    echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_cliente']}'>{$valor['nome']}</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Deletar" onclick="exibirNome()" title="Botão para confirmar a exclusão do cliente" value="Deletar cliente"> </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Brother, vê se esse link te ajuda. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253124/como-pegar-o-texto-da-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-selecionada-dentro-de-um-select

Comment: Antes de lançar uma pergunta, tente ver se já existe alguma pergunta em que a resposta atenda a sua necessidade. Essa é uma das premissas básicas que a galera pede aqui no stackoverflow. Mas é isso ai, está no caminho certo. Boa sorte!

Comment: complementando o Gato, esse é um problema de javascript/html, o seu exemplo não tem erro, apenas esta pegando uma propriedade que não te satisfaz.

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno tá ai algo que eu não esperava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua função exibirNome()

```js
function exibirNome() {
   var nome = document.querySelector("#cdcliente").value;
   if (nome) {
      alert(nome + " foi excluído(a) com sucesso");
   }
}
```

Troque `nome` por isto:

```js
function exibirNome() {
   var select = document.querySelector("#cdcliente");
   var nome = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

   if (nome) {
      alert(nome + " foi excluído(a) com sucesso");
   }
}
```

Comment: Agora entendi, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de **.value** utilize **.selectedOptions[0].text**

Isso resolverá o problema, pois vai buscar pelo texto dentro da tag  *option* selecionada, e não o valor dela.